# Solution to least squares problem using Singular Value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Let $A_{mn}$, $m\geq n$ have full column rank and $A=U_1 \Sigma V^T$ be its reduces singular value decomposition. Show that the linear least squares problem $min_{x \in R^n} \||y-Ax||_2$ is solved at $x= V \Sigma^{-1} U_1^Ty$.

Here is my attempt, just want to make sure it is correct.

Since A has full column rank there is a unique solution and that solution satisfies the normal equations, ie $A^Ty= A^TA x$.
So if we manage to show that the given x makes the right hand side of the equation equal to the left, then we are done.

$A^Ty= V \Sigma^T U_1^Ty$ and
$A^TAx=V \Sigma^T U_1^T U_1 \Sigma V^T V \Sigma^{-1} U_1^Ty= V \Sigma^T U_1^Ty$ since $V^TV=I$ and $U_1^TU_1=I$.

Hence both sides are equal and the equation is satisfied, so x is the solution.

I am just wondering whether we can use $U_1^T U_1 =I$ and $V^TV=I$ even though its the reduced singular value? Those still hold correct?

Comment: You cannot. At least not when $m\neq n$. I assume that the matrices $\Sigma$ and $V$ in your decomposition are quadratic and $U_1$ is rectangular - just as $A$. You did not specify this. However, in this case you have $V^TV = I$ but $U_1U_1^T = I$. The matrix $U_1^TU_1$ is an orthogonal projection, but this is not important. Your technique yields the result anyway.

Comment: Ah yes thats what I meant, $ U_1^TU_1=I$ and the other way around wont work as you said. So otherwise the proof/solution is correct? Thanks

Comment: Please read my comment again... $U_1^TU_1 = I$ is NOT right.

Comment: Wait...since A is m by n, and $ m \geq n$ shouldn't U be m by n and V be n x n? So $U^TU= I_n$? I tried with an example and $UU^T$ wont give I if U is m by n where m>n.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I mixed the dimensions. So, you were right from the beginning on and your solution is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir! So by uniqueness any solution that solves the normal equations is a solution and is the only one?

Comment: How does the SVD solve the least squares problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Friedrich Philipp according to Dantopa my answer is not correct since $U_1^TU_1$ does not equal $I_n$ he says?  In the last line of his answer.

Comment: Nevermind it was a typo!

Answer (score 2):

Using the singular value decomposition to solve the full column rank linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = b
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{n}, \quad 
x \in\mathcal{C}^{n}, \quad 
b \in\mathcal{C}^{n}
$$
By construction, $m\ge n$ and the matrix rank $\rho=n$.

**Singular value decomposition**

The singular value decomposition is guaranteed to exist:
$$
\mathbf{A}
= 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\Sigma \, 
\mathbf{V}^{*} 
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} &
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S}  \\
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right].
$$
Because the matrix has full column rank the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}\right)}$ is trivial.

The codomain matrix $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$, and the domain matrix $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{V}^{n\times n}$ are unitary: 
$$
\mathbf{U}^{*}\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U}\,\mathbf{U}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{m}, \quad
\mathbf{V}^{*}\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{V}\,\mathbf{V}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{n}.
$$

The column vectors of $\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times\rho}$ are an orthogonal span of $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}}(\mathbf{A})$; the column vectors of $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times\rho}$ are an orthogonal span of $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}}(\mathbf{A}^{*})$. Similarly, the column vectors of $\color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m-\rho}$ are an orthogonal span of $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A^{*}})}$.
The $\rho$ singular values are ordered and real:
$$
  \sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \ge \dots \ge \sigma_{\rho}>0.
$$
These singular values form the diagonal matrix of singular values
$$
\mathbf{S} = \text{diagonal} (\sigma_{1},\sigma_{1},\dots,\sigma_{\rho}) \in\mathbb{R}^{\rho\times\rho}.
$$
The $\mathbf{S}$ matrix is embedded in the sabot matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ whose shape insures conformality.

**Least squares solution**

Consider the case where the data vector is not the null space $b\notin\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$, and the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x - b = \mathbf{0}
$$
does not have a solution of exactly 0. Generalize the question and ask for the best solution vector $x$ which minimizes the difference $r^{2}(x) = \lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert_{2}^{2}$ in the $2-$norm. The least squares minimizers are defined as
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\left\{ 
  x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
  \big\lVert
    \mathbf{A} x - b
  \big\rVert_{2}^{2}
  \text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$

**Exploit SVD: separate range and null spaces**

Unitary transformations are invariant under the two norm. For example
$$
\lVert \mathbf{V} x \rVert_{2} = \lVert x \rVert_{2}.
$$ 
This provides a freedom to transform problems into a form easier to manipulate. In this case, 
$$
\lVert
 \mathbf{U}^{*} \mathbf{A}x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
\lVert
 \Sigma \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\rVert_{2}^{2}.
$$
Switching to the block form which separates range and null spaces,
$$
\begin{align}
r^{2}(x) = 
\big\lVert
 \Sigma\, \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
&=
\Bigg\lVert
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S} \\
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
x - 
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\[4pt]
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right]
b
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
  &=
\big\lVert
\mathbf{S}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
+
\big\lVert
\color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
\end{align}
$$

**Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse**

By varying the solution vector $x$ we can control the range space term and force it to $0$:
$$
\mathbf{S}\,
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
=
0
\qquad
\Rightarrow
\qquad
x = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}b.
$$
This is the point solution, the solution of least norm:
$$
  x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b 
= 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}b
$$
using the thin SVD.

The error term  cannot be removed, leaving a residual error: 
$$
  r^{2}\left(x_{LS}\right) = 
\big\lVert
\color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2},
$$
which quantifies how much of the data vector $b$ resides in the null space.

**Orthogonality**

Your question raises a point at times overlooked: the expression of orthogonality for the domain matrices. To be clear,
$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} 
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
  \end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
  \end{array}
\right]
=
\mathbf{I}_{n},
$$
and
$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} &
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{l}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{l}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} &
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array}
\right]
=
\mathbf{I}_{m}
$$
Keep in mind that when restricted to the range space component we get an identity matrix in only one direction:
$$
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} = \mathbf{I}_{\rho},
$$
$$
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \ne \mathbf{I}_{m}.
$$

Comment: Hi Dantopa, I think the rank should be n not m, since m$\geq n$. Also, I still don't see how $U_R^* U_R $ is not the identity, I mean I've tried all examples of matrices which are 3 by 2 or 4 by 3 which have orthonormal columns and they all give I ?

Comment: I mean writing $U_R$ in block form with columns $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ then $U_R^{*} U_R= I_n$ since you get $u_i^{*} u_i = 1$ and $u_i^{*} u_j = 0$ for all i not equal to j and you have n $ u_i^{*}$ terms each multiplying n$ u_i$ terms

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182355/a-non-square-matrix-with-orthonormal-columns Robert Israel's answer supports my claim? And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix

Comment: @Socchi Thank you for your careful reading and finding the typos. My notes are written in with $X$ and $Y$ instead of $U$ and $V$ which inspires confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I follow your answer now and thank you for all the explanation. Is my solution correct though? Thanks.

Comment: @Socchi Yes, good work on your part. Thanks for asking this question which inspires confusion. Summary: Write $\Sigma$ as a block matrix with $\mathbf{S}$ to sort this out.

Comment: Thank you your answer was quite informative. I will upvote. I will still leave the question open though as it might inspire more good explanations.